# How to modify one element of a selected element with multiple elements within?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is grab a div, clone it, modify some of its contents, and append it. I'm having a hard time modifying some of its contents though.

Here's the selector

```
$('div.checkbox:first').html()
```

Which yields the following

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Categories[cat_name][]" value="Life" checked=""> Life</label>
```

How do I change "Life" to "Peace" in both locations?  Mind you, it won't always be "Life".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bLqka8b1/)***

Changing the value of the input element is trivial, jQuery provides the function `val` for that

```
$('div.checkbox:first input[type="checkbox"]').val("Peace")
```

However, changing the text of "Life" to "Peace" is a lot harder. That is because "Life" is not inside of an element by itself, it is inside of a label which also includes an input element. In order to separate this content to change, the text nodes must be inspected. jQuery does not provide a way to do this so it must be done with native JavaScript

```
var div = $('div.checkbox:first');
//Change the input value to "Peace"
$('input[type="checkbox"]',div).val("Peace");

//locate the label element
var label = $('label',div);
//locate the last child of the child nodes of the label (this will be the textNode)
var labelText = label[0].childNodes[label[0].childNodes.length-1];
//assign the textNode's textContent value as "Peace" changing the text.
labelText.textContent = "Peace";
```

```js
var div = $('div.checkbox:first');
$('input[type="checkbox"]',div).val("Peace");
var label = $('label',div);
var labelText = label[0].childNodes[label[0].childNodes.length-1];
labelText.textContent = "Peace";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Categories[cat_name][]" value="Life" checked=""> Life</label>
</div>
```

Comment: For some odd reason, I get "undefined" for labelText. I've copied and pasted and still get the error. I'm using Yii2. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @MikelG - Can you create a jsFiddle which reproduces the undefined scenario?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. I had the wrong selector. This works perfectly! Thank you!